# Can vairagya (dispassion) and mudita(gladness) co-exist?

Tags: yoga-vashishtha

Suppose I have attained vairagya or dispassion with regards to the world then is it possible to develop mudita or gladness along with vairagya ? If yes how ?
Is gladness a correct translation of word mudita?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

**Yogasutra 1.15 (Patanjali)**

> drista anushravika vishaya vitrishnasya vashikara sanjna vairagyam

Meaning and translation:

> When the mind loses desire even for objects seen or described in a tradition or in scriptures, it acquires a state of utter (vashikara) desirelessness that is called non-attachment (vairagya).

The above is the goal. The means to achieving this goal are manifold and include the practice of

**Yogasutra 1.33 (Patanjali)**

> maitri karuna mudita upekshanam sukha duhka punya apunya vishayanam bhavanatah chitta prasadanam

Meaning and translation:

> In relationships, the mind becomes purified by cultivating feelings of friendliness towards those who are happy, compassion for those who are suffering, goodwill towards those who are virtuous, and indifference or neutrality towards those we perceive as wicked or evil.
>
> Each attitude is a type of meditation

For e.g., Buddhism has adopted maitri as metta meditation, upeksha or equanimity as samata etc.

Such meditation leads to vairagya. Having achieved vairagya, one continues to exhibit maitri, mudita, karuna and upeksha dispassionately towards all beings.

Read more here:

http://www.swamij.com/yoga-sutras-11216.htm

http://swamij.com/yoga-sutras-13339.htm

Comment: Yogasutra 1.33's translation doesn't seem right, referring to what is written above. Are 1.15 and 1.33 related (i.e. *vairagya* leads to *mudita*)?

Comment: @iammilind It is typically applied to people but can also be applied to experiences which give us happiness, sorrow etc. Vairagya is the goal and to achieve this goal there are several steps one of which is the practice of the four attitudes. Check the first link.